# Is there any alternate to increase the aws lambda invoke time or pipe the result

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

my objective is to return a stream of mp3 file which will take more than 30s time so how can increase the limit of aws api gateway or is there any way to return the result before 30s or piping the result

here is my code

```
var url = 'http://youtube.com/watch?v=' + song.youtube_video.id;
        let audio = ytdl(url, { quality: 'lowest', filter: 'audioonly' });
        let musicStream = []
        audio.on('data', function (data) {
            musicStream.push(data);
        })
        audio.on('end', function (data) {
            callback(null, musicStream);
        })
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        callback("Music Lyrics Mismatch", null);
    })
```

Comment: Is there is any special requirement? if not then why don't you use other components like s3 with the integration of CloudFront Distribution?

Answer (score 1):

Not currently, 30 seconds is a hard limit. I would recommend implementing an asynchronous model/fork and join for these integrations if they cannot complete within 30 seconds.

Comment: can you share some document link for this kind of implementation actually i am new to AWS services

Comment: You have few AWS files which you want to access like static resources?